# How to use iis rewrite?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I want to implement access to www.aaa.com:53000, rewrite as www.bbb.com:44000.
But I set the rule according to the document.

```
   <rule name="rewrite www.aaa.com" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)" negate="false" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.aaa.com" />
          <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="53000" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="www.bbb.com:44000" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    </rule>
```

Then all static file paths report an error 404.
I'm not sure I should use it that way.

Comment: I have solved the problem,But I found that it just replaced the domain name, not the port.The actual address is www.bbb.com:53000. Why?

Comment: That's not no more a simple rewrite, so you need to configure a full reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Thank you, I have set up the agent according to the documentation, but the parameter repeats when getting Request.QueryString in the project.   ex:Request.QueryString = {id=3035&dt=637223740906838254},After the reverse proxy Request.QueryString =QueryString = {id=3035&id=3035&dt=637223742774554116&dt=637223742774554116},So do I need to set anything else?

Comment: I've found the problem,I'm using <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.bbb.com/{REQUEST_URI}" />,Replacing {REQUEST_URI} with {R:1} solves this problem.I want to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a reverse proxy rule template and create the rule like below:

```
 <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://www.bbb.com:44000/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

you could refer this below link for more detail:

- https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: @AidenYan you could post your solution as an answer and mark the post. it will help other people who face a similar issues.